# Android Volley app with local nodejs server

Tags: android, json, node.js, mongodb

I'm testing the volley app to fetch a JSON data. My test succeeded from fetching it from an online site.But when I connect it to my localhost node js server it didn't fetch it and no exceptions fired in the console,there is just no response at all.Even I tested to send get request by the browser and it worked and returned the JSON data and yes I've putted the actual address of my machine not "localhost".
Thats my Nodejs server code:

```
var express=require('express');

var mongoose=require('mongoose');

//making the connections
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/db',function (error) {
if(error){console.log("error");}
else{

    console.log("connected!!");

 }

});




 //using the exported function to create the server
 var app=express();
// Port to be listened tos
var port=process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get('/api',function(req,res){

res.json({firstname:'George',lastname:'Cloney'});
});

app.listen(port);
```

AppController.java:

```
public class AppController  extends Application{

public static final String TAG = AppController.class
        .getSimpleName();

private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private ImageLoader mImageLoader;

private static AppController mInstance;

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    super.onCreate();

    mInstance = this;
}

public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    }

    return mRequestQueue;
}

public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
    getRequestQueue();
    if (mImageLoader == null) {
        mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue,
                new LruBitmapCache());
    }
    return this.mImageLoader;
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
    // set the default tag if tag is empty
    req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    req.setTag(TAG);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
    if (mRequestQueue != null) {
        mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
    }
}
}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView text;
private String url = "http://192.168.43.214:3000/api";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);

    JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            //trying to test the response length but no results also
            text.setText(" "+response.length());
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);

                    String fullname=jsonObject.getString("firstname");

                    text.setText(jsonObject.toString());

                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),fullname,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }



            //Log.v("Data from the web: " , response.toString());


        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            VolleyLog.d("Mainactivity", error.getMessage());

        }
    });

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);

}





   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long analysis I found that the object called responding json array so the solution is to return a json array in node js code simply by responding with a json array rather than a json object:

```
res.json([{,}];
```

instead of this

```
res.json({,});
```

plus putting the object responding json array and its functionality inside a method and invoke it onCreate:

```
       void getJsonArray(url){
       //like before
       }
```